# What is the Weyl transform of narrow Gaussians and/or the Dirac delta?

Tags: quantum-optics, phase-space, wigner-transform

Consider the family of Gaussians in $q$, $p$ with decreasing widths $σ$
$$Φ_σ(q,p) = \frac{2}{π σ^2} e^{-\frac{2}{σ^2}(q^2+p^2)}$$
or in complex plane coordinates
$$\tilde Φ_σ(α) = \frac{1}{π σ^2} e^{-\frac{|α|^2}{σ^2} }.$$
While the corresponding characteristic function
$$\chi_σ(β) = e^{-σ^2 β^2}$$
is well-defined for each $σ \in \mathbb{R}_ +$, there seems to be a lower bound $σ^2 \ge 1/2$ for the Weyl transform to produce an operator, namely the thermal state $ρ_\text{th}$ with $\bar n = σ^2 - 1/2$, the value of $σ^2 = 1/2$ corresponding to the pure state $|0⟩⟨0|$.

Is the Weyl transform of Gaussians narrower than the Wigner function of vacuum ill-defined, or is it just some operator which happens not to satisfy some of the conditions on density matrices? If this does not work, what exactly breaks? If it does, certainly a limit $σ → 0_+$ is possible in some respect; in such case, what would the Weyl transform of $Φ_0(q,p) = δ(q)δ(p)$ be?

Surely I could simply write
$$A_σ = \frac1π \int_{\mathbb{C}} χ_σ(β) D(-β) \mathrm{d}^2β,$$
which in the latter case would give
$$A_σ = \frac1π \int_{\mathbb{C}} D(β) \mathrm{d}^2β,$$
but I can't seem to identify what the action of such operator would excplicitly be, or even if the integral does not diverge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is that not all Gaussians are Wigner functions, and you should not think of them as such. But you may certainly Weyl-transform them!

I'm staying out of optical phase space, to which you may translate, and nondimensionalizing $\hbar=1$ for simplicity.
It is then straightforward to see, in [plain QM](https://www.hep.anl.gov/czachos/aaa.pdf), what operator your normalized phase space Gaussian transforms to,
$$
 {1\over 2\pi} \int dx dp dy  ~~\bigl  \vert ~x+\frac{ y}{2} \left  \rangle
e^{iyp}~  Φ_σ (x,p) ~\right \langle x- \frac{ y}{2}~ \bigr  |~~~\tag{142}.
$$

Taking the narrow/vanishing $\sigma\to 0$ limit, the integrals are even easier to do: they collapse to
$$
{1\over \pi} \int\!\! dx~\vert \!-\!x\rangle \langle x|  ~~~   \tag{151},
$$
the celebrated ***parity operator*** !

This, of course, cannot be a bona-fide density matrix summarizing a normalizable wave function. A fundamental requirement for a ($\hbar=1$)  phase-space function to be representing (the density matrix of) a physical wave function as a Wigner function is
$$
 |Φ_σ|\leq {1\over \pi}.
$$

- There are no spiky Wigner functions.

Comment: Ooh, a downloadable link to your book? :-o I'll read that with delight!

Comment: This works perfectly, and I knowing what to expect to reach, I was able to transform to my formalism easily. I'm feeling ashamed now because the latter was literally hiding in plain sight. I'll play with the more general version from here on. Many thanks for your time!